# SQL Attribution modelling

Tags: sql, hadoop

*I've spent days Googling,  can't find an answer *

How do I create an Equal Click Attribution model in SQL(or my case, Hadoop).

Basically, what I'm trying to do is look at a customer journey.

Suppose that person A buys a car on your website.

Person A first comes to you via Google, then again through Google later. Then a few days later, comes to your website again via an email. Finally, he types in your website address manually and buys the car for £8,000.

It's easy enough to do Last Touch Attribution and say he came in via the website to buy it.

But how, in a SQL world, do you say he bought one car, over 4 journeys, so each journey is worth £2,000 (8,000/4). And the car is 1/4 journeys.

What I'm wanting to get to is this :
Google,  2 journeys,  0.5 of the car,  £4,000
Email, 1 journey,  0.25 of the car,  £2,000
Website , 1 journey,  0.25 of the car,  £2,000

My fields are channel, orderid,  date, revenue.  I have a list of all the channels the customer used, and created a count of them. But I'm not sure how to, in a database with code,  split the orders by their channels.

It is humiliating to admit defeat and ask help. I'm trying, but I can't make SQL do this. Any ideas?

Comment: Post your sample data and the desired result. I hope you are aware that Hadoop is a MapReduce engine and not an SQL database.

Comment: I'm aware that it's map reduce and not SQL, yes. I'll try get sample data later. But Hadoop sadly is all I've got to work with

Answer (score -1):

```
Select CustId, Sum(Revenue) As TotRev, Count(CustID) As JourneyCount, Sum(Revenue)/Count(CustID) As EqualClick
From Nico
```